# Java arrays of multiple parents and children need to find out if all children of a specified parent are deletable

Tags: java, recursion, tree, parent-child

So I have the following problem. I have a tree in UI and in DB I have data showing which node has which parented, so I lose the direct connection I have in UI. I need to know if every object is deletable or not based if it's children are.
Data1

```
name    id    deletable   parentId
A       1     1           0   
B1      2     1           1   
B2      3     1           1   
C1      4     0           3   
C2      5     1           3   
D1      6     1           5
```

I get a request to delete a certain ID, I need to verify if I can delete it. The problem is that I don't have a good method of finding if the Childs all are deletable.

Ex: I get request to delete(id = 3) it won't be possible as it's child with id = 4 is not deletable.

I have options to either do this in SQL or in Java. Was thinking of the following

```
Data1[] obj = getAllData() //it will also get objects which have no direct link to the id we provided
recursiveMethod(obj, id);

recursiveMethod(Data1[] obj, currentParentId) {
     //last node
    if(obj.lenth == 1)
        return obj.getIdDeletable;
    //filter obj for childs having parentId= currentParentId
    childs[] = logic;
    for(Data1 child: childs) {
        recursiveMethod(obj, child.getId)
    } 
}
```

The data U work in backend are arrays and I start with the Id of the object I want to delete. I am stuck on how to find out if it's deletable or not

Comment: Question, where does childs[] come from? obj is an array containing all the nodes?

Comment: `I am stuck on how to find out if it's deletable or not` - Wait, you have a column `deletable` in your DB. Hence, you should know whether a particular object can be deleted by looking at its property.

Comment: In case if you want to verify if information in the `deletable` column is correct, then explain your logic. Do you need to find out whether a particular node has no children?

Comment: @Yellow, is an array of nodes containing all the node where some may not have any particular link with the chain we need.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko I know which are deletable, but a parent may have n Childs and so on.

Comment: `but a parent may have n Childs and so on` - Can you give a more elaborate exploration on what do you need to check, what should be the result (it's not clear from your pseudocode)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the methods I have available to get the data needed but I was thinking about something like this:

Edited:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{   
    int id; // = some id
    Data1[] objs = getAllData(); //it will also get objects which have no direct link to the id we provided
    boolean canDelete = isDeletable(objs[id-1], objs);
}

public static boolean isDeletable(Data1 parent, Data1[] objs) 
{
    if(parent.getIdDeletable() == 0)
        return false;
    
    
    int pid = parent.getId();
    for(Data1 o: obj)
    {
        if(o.getParentId() == pid && !isDeletable(o, objs))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Steps:

1. If the parent cannot be deleted return false
2. Else check every child
3. If there is a child that cannot be deleted return false
4. Else return true

Which means that the function returns true is the object and its children can be deleted.